How is Jenkins implemented for multiple branches
just wanna know how is Jenkinsfile used among multiple branches in a company , single Jenkinsfile for multiple branches with conditionals or any other way or plugins?  i dont mind using multiple jenkinsfile but implementing it and merge would cause a overwrite i think
I have 3 main, dev , release and a feature branch which should be triggered based on pull-requests to dev.
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        BRANCH_NAME = env.BRANCH_NAME ?: 'unknown'
        CHANGE_ID = env.CHANGE_ID ?: ''
    }

    stages {
        stage('Initialize') {
            steps {
                echo "Building branch: ${BRANCH_NAME}"
                echo "Pull Request ID: ${CHANGE_ID}"
            }
        }

        stage('Build') {
            when {
                anyOf {
                    branch 'main'
                    branch 'dev'
                    expression { return env.CHANGE_ID != '' } // For pull requests
                }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    if (BRANCH_NAME == 'main') {
                        echo "Building main branch"
                        // Main branch-specific build steps
                        sh 'echo Main branch build process'
                    } else if (BRANCH_NAME == 'dev') {
                        echo "Building dev branch"
                        // Dev branch-specific build steps
                        sh 'echo Dev branch build process'
                    } else if (env.CHANGE_ID != '') {
                        echo "Building feature branch for PR to dev"
                        // Feature branch-specific build steps
                        sh 'echo Feature branch build process'
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Test') {
            when {
                anyOf {
                    branch 'main'
                    branch 'dev'
                    expression { return env.CHANGE_ID != '' } // For pull requests
                }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    if (BRANCH_NAME == 'main') {
                        echo "Testing main branch"
                        // Main branch-specific test steps
                        sh 'echo Main branch testing process'
                    } else if (BRANCH_NAME == 'dev') {
                        echo "Testing dev branch"
                        // Dev branch-specific test steps
                        sh 'echo Dev branch testing process'
                    } else if (env.CHANGE_ID != '') {
                        echo "Testing feature branch for PR to dev"
                        // Feature branch-specific test steps
                        sh 'echo Feature branch testing process'
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy') {
            when {
                anyOf {
                    branch 'main'
                    branch 'dev'
                    expression { return env.CHANGE_ID != '' } // For pull requests
                }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    if (BRANCH_NAME == 'main') {
                        echo "Deploying main branch"
                        // Main branch-specific deployment steps
                        sh 'echo Main branch deployment process'
                    } else if (BRANCH_NAME == 'dev') {
                        echo "Deploying dev branch"
                        // Dev branch-specific deployment steps
                        sh 'echo Dev branch deployment process'
                    } else if (env.CHANGE_ID != '') {
                        echo "Deploying feature branch for PR to dev"
                        // Feature branch-specific deployment steps
                        sh 'echo Feature branch deployment process'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            echo 'Cleaning up...'
            // Clean up actions, e.g., deleting temporary files
        }
        success {
            echo 'Pipeline succeeded!'
        }
        failure {
            echo 'Pipeline failed!'
        }
    }
}



Create Jenkinsfile in the repository
Create a Jenkins "Multi-Branch Pipeline" Job that makes use of the Jenkinsfile

You can configure the job to recognize and build branches and pull requests.
If necessary, in the Jenkinsfile you can add conditional build steps depending on branches / the branch being the main branch or a tag build. If you don't need specific branch behavior, you don't have to add them as conditions to the steps or stages.
The Jenkinsfile will be the same across the branches.
